# RxJs: Load related resources

Tags: rxjs

I'm struggling to achieve the following sequence of operations:

1. Make an API call, **get the data** from the response. In response I will have property which is an array of endpoints pointing at related resources.
   For instance: `{ ..., relatedResources: ['my.app/api/resource/1', 'my.app/api/resource/2'] }`
2. **Map each of endpoints from  `relatedResources` to http request**, get the data from each of the responses so I can have actual resources array instead of endpoints array. To illustrate what should be achieved:
   `['my.app/api/resource/1', 'my.app/api/resource/2'] => [{...}, {...}]`
3. **Combine** data from step 1 and step 2 which is basically data from the 1st step with mapped `realtedResources` property (containing data, not just endpoints)

How can I achieve this and which operators would be useful for my case?

Comment: Try testing the flatMap operator

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try this:

```js
response$.pipe(
  switchMap(
    response => forkJoin(
      response.relatedResources.map(resource => this.apiService.makeRequest(resource))
    ).pipe(
      // you can perform all sorts of transformations here
      // since you have access to both the initial `response`
      // and the resulted data
      map(resourcesResArray => ({
        ...response,
        relatedResources: resourcesResArray,
      }))
    )
  )
)
```

`forkJoin` takes in an array of observables(or an object whose values are observables) and will subscribe to all of them and will emit either an array with all the responses from each observable & a `complete` notification, in case all the given observables had emitted *at least* one value and completed, or simply a `complete` notification, in case all of the observables completed and at least one did not send any value.

[Here's](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/forkJoin.ts#L134) the `forkJoin` implementation, it's worth taking a look and it's also very interesting.

Then, by using a closure, we can reference the initial `response` object, which contains the `endpoints`.

Also, this approach assumes that `this.apiService.makeRequest` returns an observable which completes after it emits its response.